# Checking if naughts or crosses win in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: php, programming-challenge, array, tic-tac-toe

I am working on a coding challenge for Tic Tac Toe. I am calculating the results and inserting them into the database.

However I have a long and messy if statement, which checks if the array's values match a valid win for O or X.
I feel like it could be refactored down but I'm unsure on how to approach this.

```
    /** @var int */
protected $xWins = 0;

/** @var int */
protected $oWins = 0;

/** @var int */
protected $draws = 0;

/**
 */
public function __construct()
{
    // creates a new database on object creation
    $this->database = new Database();
}

    public function winner(string $input)
    {
        $input = str_replace("\\n", "", $input);

        $length = strlen($input);

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++) {
            if ($i % 9 === 0) {

                $result = substr($input, $i - 9, 9);

                if ($result[0] === "X" && $result[1] === "X" && $result[2] === "X") {
                    $winner = "X";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->xWins++;
                } else if ($result[3] === "X" && $result[4] === "X" && $result[5] === "X") {
                    $winner = "x";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->xWins++;
                } else if ($result[6] === "X" && $result[7] === "X" && $result[8] === "X") {
                    $winner = "X";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->xWins++;
                } else if ($result[0] === "X" && $result[3] === "X" && $result[6] === "X") {
                    $winner = "X";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->xWins++;
                } else if ($result[1] === "X" && $result[4] === "X" && $result[7] === "X") {
                    $winner = "X";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->xWins++;
                } else if ($result[2] === "X" && $result[5] === "X" && $result[8] === "X") {
                    $winner = "X";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->xWins++;
                } else if ($result[0] === "X" && $result[4] === "X" && $result[8] === "X") {
                    $winner = "X";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->xWins++;
                } else if ($result[2] === "X" && $result[4] === "X" && $result[6] === "X") {
                    $winner = "X";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->xWins++;
                }

                // checks for O lines
                else if ($result[0] === "O" && $result[1] === "O" && $result[2] === "O") {
                    $winner = "o";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->oWins++;;
                } else if ($result[3] === "O" && $result[4] === "O" && $result[5] === "O") {
                    $winner = "o";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->oWins++;
                } else if ($result[6] === "O" && $result[7] === "O" && $result[8] === "O") {
                    $winner = "o";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->oWins++;
                } else if ($result[0] === "O" && $result[3] === "O" && $result[6] === "O") {
                    $winner = "o";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->oWins++;
                } else if ($result[1] === "O" && $result[4] === "O" && $result[7] === "O") {
                    $winner = "O";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->oWins++;
                } else if ($result[2] === "O" && $result[5] === "O" && $result[8] === "O") {
                    $winner = "O";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->oWins++;
                } else if ($result[0] === "O" && $result[4] === "O" && $result[8] === "O") {
                    $winner = "O";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->oWins++;
                } else if ($result[2] === "O" && $result[4] === "O" && $result[6] === "O") {
                    $winner = "O";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->oWins++;
                    // checks for draw
                } else {
                    $winner = "Draw";
                    $this->database->insert($winner, $result);
                    $this->draws++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: May we see a realistic sample input (a couple of games passed to this method)?  I think I can reverse engineer one from your code logic, but it would be better if I could have my assumptions confirmed.  Why aren't x's and o's saved to the database consistently (regarding upper/lowercase)?

Comment: Are unused cells of the gameboard filled with a visible character or are spaces used? I am assuming the game short-circuits to a winner as soon as a winner is determined.

Comment: In your next questions, please post the _complete_ code of a file. This code is missing the `class` declaration, which makes it harder than necessary for potential reviewers to run your code.

Comment: Please don't modify your code after receiving answers.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of a Battleship gameboard parser that I once designed.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47595575/2943403  a rare case where regex outperforms non-regex techniques.

I am going to recommend a class variable that is an associative array so that variable variables can be avoided.  By filling each subarray with the respective `$result` strings, you compress your required data into a single structure instead of having a collection of results and a win/draw incrementer.

```
protected $outcomes = [
    'X' => [],
    'O' => [],
    'D' => []
];
```

Your `str_replace()`, `strlen()`, and subsequent modulus-based looping is definitely working too hard.  It will be far simpler to break the string into substrings by using:

```
foreach (explode('\n', $input) as $result) {
```

Now that game results are properly separated, you can use a regular expression to concisely parse the string and return the outcome as a single letter.

A "branch reset" (`(?|...)`) is used so that the matching character is always `\1` throughout each branch versus `\1`, `\2`, `\3`, `\4`. The `x` pattern flag allows me to use spaces and comments to separate and explain pattern logic.

```
public assessGames($input) {
    foreach (explode('\n', $input) as $result) {
        $outcome = preg_match(
            '~(?|
                ^(?:.{3}){0,2}(\S)\1{2}   #horizontal win
                |(\S)(?:.{2}\1){2}        #or vertical win
                |^(\S)(?:.{3}\1){2}       #or diagonalLTR win
                |^.{2}(\S)(?:.\1){2}      #or diagonalRTL win
              )~x',
            $result,
            $match
        )
        ? $match[1]  // X or O
        : 'D';
        $this->outcomes[$outcome][] = $result;
    }
}
```

Note, if you are parsing a high volume of games, you may like to refactor this approach to skip the explode&iterate step and make a single `preg_match_all()` call.

Now that your outcomes are fully evaluated, then saved to the class variable, make as few trips to the database as possible.  I always discourage making looped trips to the db.  I don't know what utilities you have in your database class, but using a batch insert technique will be beneficial here.

If/When you need to know how many wins/losses/draws a player has, just count the elements in the class variable.

Granted, the four-part pattern that I have designed may seem like incomprehensible magic to someone who is not familiar with the syntax, but by studying the pattern explanation at regex101.com, you can learn the full meaning.  I have labeled each pattern to aid in understanding what each is doing.

Be sure to break your class functionality into separate methods so that each method has a "single responsibility".

Comment: You have "hardcoded" variable names like `$xWins` and `$oWins`.  For my answer to cooperate with your variable naming convention, I would need to take my `$match[1]` and use dynamic variable syntax.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/using-braces-with-dynamic-variable-names-in-php  This (anti-pattern) is almost always a symptom of bad code design.  To prevent this, I am naming three keys in an array to store the outcomes.  This is a clean and logic design because the values are sensibly related.

Comment: You can replace my "you" for "the OP" then.  I am trying to explain.  What is still foggy?  I don't want to keep the OP's indidualized variables because then my `preg_` result would need to be like `++${ strtolower($match[1]) . 'Wins'};` and that is a mess.  I am recommending a wholly refined storage technique and a change to what exactly is being stored in the class level variable.

Comment: No, I am not calling them the same thing.  Variable variables are the problem.  An associative array is the solution/replacement.  I don't recommend the use of `$xWins` and `$oWins` -- I am recommending an associative array to eliminate those variables. `protected $outcomes`

Comment: No bother, maybe I didn't explain myself very well.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call myself an expert, but I finished a tic-tac-toe project today as well, I was writing Python, so my suggestions might not be idiomatic for PHP - but I think this will apply to your situation as well.

Your intuition is solid. Every time you find yourself using cut and paste, this is probably a sign you can put the code inside a function.

Idea One:

For example, create a function inside winner - this contains the valid win matching mode. this function takes a parameter "x_or_o" - which is either a string 'x' or a string 'o'.

This should be a great start because it will cut your checking code in half. Let's see if we can do better.

Idea Two:

I notice that your code doesn't care about whether a player has a winning row, or a winning column. In this case, you can assign your logical operators to a variable.
e.g.

```
public function win_check(string $x_or_o) {
    top_row_win = $result[1] === x_or_o && $result[4] === x_or_o && $result[7] === x_or_o
    mid_row_win = $result[2] === x_or_o && $result[5] === x_or_o && $result[8] === x_or_o
    ...

    win = (top_row_win || mid_row_win || bottom_row_win || left_col_win || mid_col_win || right_col_win || diagonal_win || off_diagonal_win)

    if (win) {
    $winner = x_or_o;
    $this->database->insert($winner, $result)
    if (x_or_o == 'x'){
    xWins++   
}
    elif (x_or_o == 'o') {
    oWins++
}
}
}

//Then in your outer scope, your win_check function will be called from winner like this.

win_check(x)
win_check(o)
```

Idea Three:

In my project, I used a 2d array and used index slicing to do this more elegantly. I do not know what array slicing or index slicing is possible in PHP.